# jasmine-node does not see tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I'm using jasmine-node and am calling it with

`node.exe path/to/jasmine_node --verbose path/to/my_file.js`

This works in the sense that Jasmine-node gets invoked and complains if the path is wrong, but doesn't seem to find any tests. Here is the output I'm getting:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Dropbox\Projects\Demos\web\node_modules\jasmine-node\bin\jasmine-node --verbose --captureExceptions foo\bar.js
undefined

Finished in 0.002 seconds
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

The contents of `bar.js` definitely contain a test.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

`npx humile foo\bar.js`.

If it doesn't see any specs too, check the output of

`npx humile foo\bar.js --show-specs`

If the output of the command is absolute path to the file, then something is wrong with your spec, not with test runner.